# Draw custom Shapes and curved rectangle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jointjs

While I have been using jointJs for a long time, I still have one problem. I need to draw custom Shapes using Lines. I am using the following code to draw a rectangle:

```
joint.V(MyPaper.viewport).append(joint.V("rect", { x: 145, y: 70, width: 260, height: 70 }));
```

Is there is any way to draw a curved rectangle and custom shapes?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is using the `path` tag as example. With this you can draw whatever you want. SVG files using it, too. The [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.6/joint.html) is a good first step.

**Code**

```
// Import stylesheets
import "./style.css";
import * as joint from "jointjs";

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph();
new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: document.getElementById("app"),
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  model: graph,
  interactive: { linkMove: false },
  defaultConnectionPoint: {
    name: "boundary",
    args: {
      extrapolate: true,
      sticky: true
    }
  },
  validateConnection: function() {
    return false;
  }
});

// Custom Link

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
  markup: [
    {
      tagName: "path",
      selector: "p1"
    },
    {
      tagName: "circle",
      selector: "c1"
    },
    {
      tagName: "path",
      selector: "p2"
    },
    {
      tagName: "circle",
      selector: "x"
    }
  ],
  source: { x: 20, y: 20 },
  target: { x: 300, y: 280 },
  vertices: [{ x: 150, y: 280 }],
  attrs: {
    p1: {
      connection: true,
      fill: "none",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 6,
      strokeLinejoin: "round"
    },
    p2: {
      connection: true,
      fill: "none",
      stroke: "#fe854f",
      strokeWidth: 4,
      pointerEvents: "none",
      strokeLinejoin: "round",
      targetMarker: {
        type: "path",
        fill: "#fe854f",
        stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        d: "M 10 -3 10 -10 -2 0 10 10 10 3"
      }
    },
    x: {
      r: 10,
      stroke: "black",
      fill: "#fe854f",
      atConnectionRatio: 0.1,
      strokeWidth: 1,
      event: "myclick:circle",
      opacity: 0
    }
  }
});

graph.resetCells([link]);

window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(link.prop("markup"));
  link.set(
    "markup",
    link.prop("markup").concat({
      tagName: "circle",
      selector: "x1"
    })
  );
  // link.attr("attrs/x/display", "block");
  times(3, async () => {
    link.transition("attrs/x/opacity", 1, { duration: 100 });
    const duration = 1250;
    link.transition("attrs/x/atConnectionRatio", 0.9, { duration });
    await delay(duration - 100);
    link.transition("attrs/x/opacity", 0, { duration: 100 });
    await delay(100);
    link.transition("attrs/x/atConnectionRatio", 0.1, { duration: 0 });
    await delay(50);
  });
});

async function times(count: number, fn: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
  let index = 0;
  while (index < count) {
    await fn();
    index++;
  }
}

function delay(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

[Here](https://jointjs.stackblitz.io) is all in Stackblitz.

*And the Result:*

[image]

### To draw your bag like this (sorry... quick and dirty)

[image]

I use this code:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
import * as joint from 'jointjs';

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph();
new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: document.getElementById('app'),
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  model: graph,
  interactive: { linkMove: false },
  defaultConnectionPoint: {
    name: 'boundary',
    args: {
      extrapolate: true,
      sticky: true,
    },
  },
  validateConnection: function () {
    return false;
  },
});

// Custom Link

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
  markup: [
    {
      tagName: 'path',
      selector: 'p1',
    },
    {
      tagName: 'path',
      selector: 'p2',
    },
  ],
  source: { x: 50, y: 0 },
  target: { x: 0, y: 0 },

  attrs: {
    p1: {
      connection: true,
      fill: 'none',
      strokeWidth: 6,
      strokeLinejoin: 'round',
      targetMarker: {
        type: 'path',
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'blue',
        'stroke-width': 2,
        d: 'm 50.896114,64.34417 h 84.321566 c 4.432,0 8.22239,3.573583 8,8 l -4.49717,89.5106 c -0.22239,4.42642 0.92917,8 -3.50283,8 H 50.896114 c -4.432,0 -4.369478,-3.57131 -4.540636,-8 l -3.459364,-89.5106 c -0.171158,-4.428694 3.568,-8 8,-8 z',
      },
    },
    p2: {
      connection: true,
      fill: 'none',
      stroke: 'pink',
      strokeWidth: 0,
      pointerEvents: 'none',
      strokeLinejoin: 'round',
      targetMarker: {
        type: 'path',
        fill: '#fe854f',
        stroke: 'black',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        d: 'm 41.133796,92.45404 25.218478,3.843799 27.541231,-2.096617 27.873045,1.397745 23.55937,-3.144927',
      },
    },
  },
});

graph.resetCells([link]);
```

Here is the updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-21rhbo?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry, but this isn't what I wanted. When the paper is loaded, I need a Custom Element to be drawn automatically. The link is not intended to draw a custom element.

Comment: Can you show me what you wanna draw?

Comment: As I mentioned an image in my question, I am interested in it. @Flo, please take a look at this. Thank you

Comment: Then it's exactly what you want. A `path` to draw. With `path` you can draw whatever you want. The arrow was only an example. Or draw complex images in svg and add it inside your app. Look at the updated answer!

Comment: That's great, Flo, I'll check it out